# How do I handle a Webkit Table Column width discrepancy?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, webkit

I have encountered slightly odd behaviour in webkit browsers:

I have a table set to 100% width of its container, and each of the columns have an equal pixel width. In the gecko browsers and in IE the columns scale evenly and remain an equal width.

In the webkit browsers the width of the columns is inconsistent, depending on the width of the outer container, at some container widths, the left most columns are 1px narrower.

I am using the table as a grid background for a gant chart display, and this discrepancy is causing a misallignment with the divs that are rendered at the correct widths and offset above the table.

Have any of you encountered this before, and is there a way to force it to render the column widths consistently, or am I going to have to manually draw the grid using the canvas?

A sub question: If I do need to use the canvas, what would be the most efficient way to draw the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if there is no documentation regarding this topic. canvas would not be suitable because I need the application to work in IE <9. I have resorted to placing a grid of divs instead which are scaled via javascript. While this takes more processing power, it is probably semantically more correct as well as accurate enough for my application.